# How to pass Drop Down value to a Template Helper. [Meteor + Blaze]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I'm trying to create a template such that there is a drop down list at the beginning being populated via mongo. I have a second template that displays a table which contains further details based on the selection made above. For me to display the contents in the table, I must first be able to retrieve the value that has been selected from the dropdown. How exactly do I do that?

I tried to retrieve it using `this.schemaName` and `defaultTemplate.schemaName`, however it didn't help.

**Template:**

```
<template name ='defaultTemplate'>

    <div class="form-group" data-required="true">
        <label for="Schema" class="control-label">Select the Schema</label>
        <select required="true"  class="form-control">
            <!-- <option default>Select Schema </option> -->
            {{ #each schemaNames}}
            <option >{{schemaName}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    {{> tableTemplate}}
</template>

<template name="tableTemplate">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 85px">Label</td>
          <td>Current Value</td>
          <td style="width: 250px">New Value</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each schemaLabels}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{this.label}}</td>
            <td>{{this.value}}</td>
            <td>
            {{#autoForm id=makeUniqueID type="update" collection=Defaults doc=this autosave=true}}
              {{> afFormGroup name="value" label=false}}
            {{/autoForm}}
            </td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

**Helper:**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import '../templates/defaultTemplate.html';

Template.defaultTemplate.helpers({
   schemaNames: function () {
       return Defaults.find({},{schemaName:1}).map(function(c) {return {schemaName : c.schemaName};
       });
   },
   schemaLabels: function() {
       var selectedSchema = defaultTemplate.schemaName;
      // alert (selectedSchema); >>>>>>>>>> Displays Undefined <<<<<<<<<<<
       return Defaults.find({schemaNeme:selectedSchema},{schemaName:0,_id:0}).map(function(c) {return {label : c.label, value: c.value};
       });
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383355/correct-way-to-disable-multiple-textarea-checkbox-depends-on-the-dropdown-box)

Basically, you create a reactive var in your template to store the "state" of the dropdown, the state in this case being the value that is selected.  You then have an event handler that updates the state as the value changes (I would use both `click` and `change` on the dropdown, maybe a few others).  Finally you have a helper that returns some info based on the state.

The info you return from your helper varies based on what you are using it for.  In some cases you will want to return a true/false type response, like "this component should be disabled", but in other cases, like yours, I think you want to return the value of the dropdown and actually pass that value to your table template.  Your table template should then decide what to display based on that passed-in value.  For instance, if I pass in `null` or `undefined`, then my table would maybe display a "disabled" table with an overlay saying "No selection made", but if I pass in a value, then use that value in a subscription to get the data to populate the table.  In this way, no matter what value is passed in, the table should ALWAYS be able to display something.

Comment: Thank you @CodeChimp. After mulling over it for quite a bit, I did acutally end up doing something similar to the answer you've provided in the link. Instead of setting true/false values, I ended up setting a Session variable using Session.set and then retrieving that within the helper using Session.get.

Comment: Yup, the key is the helper that reads the reactive value.  Since Session is reactive, it works the same way.  Only catch-22 with using Session is that the session survives the template reload (leave and come back to that page and you will still have the same values selected).  That might be desirable, but might not, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template name ='defaultTemplate'>

<div class="form-group" data-required="true">
    <label for="Schema" class="control-label">Select the Schema</label>
    <select required="true"  class="form-control">
        <!-- <option default>Select Schema </option> -->
        {{ #each schemaNames}}
        <option >{{schemaName}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
//you need to pass the reactive var that contains selected schema name to tableTemplate
{{> tableTemplate selectedSchemaVar=getSelectedSchemaVar}}
</template>

<template name="tableTemplate">

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 85px">Label</td>
      <td>Current Value</td>
      <td style="width: 250px">New Value</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each schemaLabels}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{this.label}}</td>
        <td>{{this.value}}</td>
        <td>
        {{#autoForm id=makeUniqueID type="update" collection=Defaults doc=this autosave=true}}
          {{> afFormGroup name="value" label=false}}
        {{/autoForm}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
</template>
```

**JS**:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import '../templates/defaultTemplate.html';


Template.defaultTemplate.onCreated(function(){
this.selectedSchema = new ReactiveVar();
})
Template.defaultTemplate.events({
"change .form-control":function(evt,temp){
t.selectedSchema.set(evt.target.value)
}
})
Template.defaultTemplate.helpers({
schemaNames: function () {
   return Defaults.find({},{schemaName:1}).map(function(c) {return {schemaName : c.schemaName};
   });
 },
getSelectedSchemaVar:function(){
return Template.instance().selectedSchema
}
})
Template.tableTemplate.helpers({
 schemaLabels: function() {
 var selectedSchema = `Template.instance().data.selectedSchemaVar.get();`
return Defaults.find({schemaNeme:selectedSchema},{schemaName:0,_id:0}).fetch().map(function(c) {return {label : c.label, value: c.value};
});


}
});
```