# Correct way to disable multiple Textarea / checkbox depends on the dropdown box's Value

Tags: meteor

I'm looking for an effective way to enable / disable multiple controls (textarea, checkbox) through dropbox.  I.e. Selecting item A in dropbox will disable certain controls, while selecting item B in dropbox will disable some other controls.  Codes on how I approach with disabling textbox:

HTML:

> ```
> <template name="Gender">
> <input  disabled={{shouldBeDisabled}} class="input" type="text"/>
> </template>
>
> <template name="DoB">
> <textarea rows="3" cols="27" disabled={{shouldBeDisabled}}>purpose</textarea>
> </template>
> ```

js:

> ```
> Template.registerHelper("shouldBeDisabled", function() {
>   return true
> });
> ```

Question 1:  Do we require a *registerHelper* function for each individual control?  In the code above it seems like the registerhelper will either disable or enable ***both*** control as oppose to individual, but having multiple registerhelper seems redundant.

Question 2: How can we control the value in registerHelper via dropbox (i.e. select)?  I can return the value from the dropbox, is building a switch inside registerhelper the correct way and how does it incorporate into question 1?

Question 3: Is there a build-in function to add visual effect on disabled controls? (i.e.grey out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past w/ Meteor and Blaze is to setup a event listener on the dropdown that sets a reactive var/session variable that I then read in a helper.  The helper would return the string "disabled" depending on the value.

For instance (this is from memory...I don't have access to Meteor right now, and I have switched over to React/Mantra):

```
Template.MyComponent.oncreated(function() {
  this.isDropdownDisabled = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.MyComponent.events({
  'change #myDropdown'(event) {
    this.isDropdownDisabled.set($('#myDropdown').val() == 'Selected' ? true : false);
  }
});

Template.MyComponent.helpers({
  isDropdownSelected() {
    return this.isDropdownDisabled.get() == true ? '' : 'disabled';
  }
});

<select id="myDropdown">
  <option value="Not Selected">Not Selected</option>
  <option value="Selected">Select Me</option>
</select>

<input id="myDynamicallyDisabledInput" type="textbox" name="dnyamic1" {{isDropdownSelected}} />
```

That should roughly be correct.  Basic idea is that you use a reactive var to store the "state" of the dropdown value, flip the "state" when that value changes, and use a help in the inputs to determine if the `disabled` attribute needs to be set or not.  Since helper functions are reactive by default, swapping the state var will cause the template to re-evaluate any time the dropdown value changes.

Anyone can feel free to edit this response to clean up any bad code above, as again I haven't used Blaze in some time and I did this all from memory.

Comment: Following up on the answer here (and hijacking), is it possible for me to have a bunch of default values being pre-selected and filled into the disabled fields, and still be persisted in the backend? Say for Eg - salary > 30000 should disable a select field, but the select field should by default pick up a certain value.

Comment: You would need to "seed" the reactive var(s) value(s) somehow, probably when you create them, to set the initial state correctly.  In my example it assumes nothing is selected up-front, but that might not be the case.  Also, don't have to make your reactive vars a simple string.  It could be a value you are pulling from a collection, and it doesn't have to be a single value, it could be a reactive dict (dictionary) or whatever suites.  The key pieces is that you need to store something reactively (in Session or other) and use helpers to read it in the template.

Comment: @CodeChimp I sort of getting what you did there but how feasible it is to apply it on multiple controls (say textarea) with a single dropdown?  Is it required to have a helper for each textarea>

Comment: I would say you could have a helper for each possible "state".  For instance, if I had a checkbox, and the checked/unchecked state determines what shows, then I could have either 1 or 2 helpers to represent both states.  But, say I have a dropdown with 5 different states, two have the same options, then I might have either 4 or 5 helpers for `isState1Selected`, etc.  Multiple inputs can call the same helper to check the "state".

Comment: @CodeChimp Again thanks!  It sounds like a nested condition with multiple states, i.e. if there are 5 states and 5 controls, there will be a total of 25 helps created.  Now I haven't really start building it, but we can confirm this is one better way to approach?

Comment: Basically the whole idea is like a webpage with different forms listed in a dropdown menu, and the fields listed on the page is enabled / disabled depends on which form is being selected.

Comment: Well, you can pass in values to the helper functions.  So, in theory, you could have 1 helper and pass in something to that you use in that help to switch the returned value.  A `switch` may be a good choice.  The concept is still the same, though, in that you are returning `'disabled`' or `''` depending on if the given component needs to be visible, tested against a value either in Session or a reactive var (or reactive dictionary)

Comment: Thanks @CodeChimp I will give a a try.  If you don't mind i will pm you if i've further question regarding to this post